# How can I open a JSONL file in DBeaver

Tags: sqlite, dbeaver, jsonlines

I am using DBeaver 22.0.5, and when I try to open a jsonl (json lines formnat) file, I get an "unsupported command" error.
My objective is to open the jsonl file and to run some SQL commands to unnest the data in the file and put it a useful table format.
I am connected to a SQLITE db engine.
Any help would be appreciated.